# Converting Map<Long, List<Foo>> to List<Foo>

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I have a structure like this:

```
Map<Long, List<Foo>>
```

where class `Foo` exposes method:

```
Class Foo {
     public List<Bar> getBars();
     public void setBars(List<Bar> bars);
}
```

Now I want to convert this map to `List` parametrized with `Foo` class where each item in this list is `Foo` instance with aggregated bars list for given long value. For example with map:

```
{1: [Foo1, Foo2],
 2: [Foo3]}
```

where

```
Foo1.bars = [Bar1, Bar2]
Foo2.bars = [Bar3]
Foo3.bars = [Bar4, Bar5]
```

I want to get as a result:

```
[FooA, FooB]
```

where

```
FooA.bars = [Bar1, Bar2, Bar3]
FooB.bars = [Bar4, Bar5]
```

What would be the most elegant solution for this in Java 8?
Some of the `Foo` instances from map can be reused if necessary as they are not used anymore after this operation.

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Comment: @PhilippSander I'm trying to map database records from inner join with one to many relationship to my domain entity.

Comment: @PhilippSander tried the usual Java 7 solution: I took values from map. Then iterate through each List<Foo> and for each list iterate through its elements to create aggregated object, but I don't like this solution. I was thinking whether it is possible with streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Foo(List<Bar> bars)` constructor it's quite easy:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

List<Foo> result = map.values()
    .stream()
    .map(
        foos -> new Foo(foos.stream()
                    .flatMap(foo -> foo.getBars().stream())
                    .collect(toList())))
    .collect(toList());
```

We take the stream of the original map values (we don't care about keys), which are lists of `Foo`. Each such list we flatten to get the stream of `Bar`, collect them to list and pass this list to the `Foo(List<Bar>)` constructor, so we get new `Foo` objects. Finally we collect them to the `List`.

If you don't have the `Foo(List<Bar>)`, only setter, you should first create an empty `Foo`, then use the setter and return the created `Foo`:

```
List<Foo> result = map.values()
    .stream()
    .map(foos -> {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            f.setBars(foos.stream().flatMap(
                foo -> foo.getBars().stream()).collect(toList()));
            return f;
        })
    .collect(toList());
```

If you don't want to create new `Foo` objects (for example, there are additional properties you want to keep), it's better to introduce not the `setBars`, but `addBars` method (which adds new bars to the existing ones) like this:

```
public class Foo {
    ...
    public Foo addBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars.addAll(bars);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `reduce` terminal operation to combine the foos:

```
List<Foo> result = map.values()
        .stream()
        .map(foos -> foos.stream()
             .reduce((foo1, foo2) -> foo1.addBars(foo2.getBars())).get())
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in similar manner without such constructor? Or do I have to stay with the solution written in comment above?

Comment: @slakomy How do you add the List<Bar> to the Foo object?

Comment: @slakomy, `foos -> {Foo f = new Foo();f.setBars(foos.stream()...);return f;}`?

Comment: @TagirValeev please edit your answer so I can mark it as correct. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @slakomy, added also new Foo()/setBars version.